# Another "need to pull data from two tables in cakephp"

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model

Ok, I have two tables, users and units.  'Unit' belongsTo 'User', and 'User' hasMany 'Unit'.  I would like to access all of the data from my units table, and append SOME of the data from my users table for the view.  Here is my controller code:

```
public function condos() {
    $u=$this->User->Unit->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('type'=>'condo',     'active'=>1)));
    $this->set('allcondos', $u);
}
```

I have two models, User and Unit, here is the code for them:
  from unit.php:

```
class Unit extends AppModel {
    var $name='Unit';
    var $belongsTo=array(
        'User'=>array(
        'className'=>'User',
        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
    ) );
}
```

and from user.php:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name='User';
    var $hasMany=array(
        'Unit'=>array(
        'className'=>'Unit',
        'foreignKey'=>'user_id'
    ) );
}
```

Here is my view code:

```
<?php foreach ($allcondos as $condo) { ?>

<section class="listings">
<figure>
<img src="<?php echo $condo['Unit']['photo1']; ?>" />
</figure>
<h1><?php echo $condo['Unit']['complex'], ' ', $condo['Unit']['unitnum']; ?></h1>
<h2><?php echo $condo['Unit']['city']; ?>, <?php echo $condo['Unit']['state']; ?> | (<?php echo $condo['User']['area_code']; ?>)<?php echo $condo['User']['exchange'];?>-<?php echo $condo['User']['sln'];?></h2>
<p><?php echo $condo['Unit']['unit_desc']; ?></p>
</section>
<?php } ?>
```

I have a problem with the call to $condo['User']['any_field'] as it returns zero 'User' data.  (It returns the 'Unit' data just fine).  I don't know how to access both tables, obviously.

If I debug $allcondos in the view, it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Unit] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => caribeincrentals
                [additional fields] ...
            )

        [User] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [user_id] => 
                [additional fields] ...
            )

    )
    [1] => Array ...
)
```

Comment: what is your table structure?

Comment: i have a table users that has a bunch of info, including a field for 'user_id'. I have a units table that has bunch of info, including a field for 'user_id'. I altered my code again in my controller to say this: public function condos() { $this->User->Unit->Behaviors->load('Containable'); $u=$this->User->Unit->find('all', array( 'conditions'=>array( 'Unit.type'=>'condo', 'Unit.active'=>1), 'contain'=>array('User') )); $this->set('allcondos', $u); } and now I get data for units, PLUS the FIELDS for the users table but no data for the fields in the associative array

Comment: Does it work if you ignore `containable` behavior and instead specify `recursive` in your `find()`?

Comment: I tried setting it to 1 first on $this->User->Unit, then $this->User, then $this->Unit, and none of them worked.

Comment: please post the output of `debug( $allcondos );` in your view.

Comment: Please visit this link and you can see the array printed.  http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/condos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your database details, it is tough to say exactly what is going on.  However, you seem to be using a string value as the foreignKey that links your 2 models together.  This is a bad idea.

I suggest changing the `user_id` fk to an int datatype that references the id key column on the Users table (well, assuming that `id` is an autoincrementing integer value).

It's tough to say if this is the exact problem, but it's definitely worth checking out and will help you avoid some other headaches in the future.

**UPDATE**

If you structure your tables according to Cake conventions, most of the associative work will be done for you.  Here's how I would do it:

Users table ('users'):

```
id        primary key (int)
```

User model:

```
$hasMany = array( 'Unit' );
```

Units table ('units'):

```
id        primary key (int)
user_id   corresponds to id in users table
```

Unit model:

```
$belongsTo = array( 'User' );
```

If you set your tables & models up like that, Cake will automatically associate 'user_id' in the units table with 'id' in the users table.

Comment: Can you explain to me why this is a bad idea?  If I have x number of users, that may each have x number of units, how can I ever match them by id, as it is autoincrementing?  I am confused.  I thought I was supposed to have one field in each table that matches up exactly with the other?

Comment: @HeatherWalters It creates extra maintenance burden for you.  `id` is already unique, auto-incrementing (has a default value), and small.  `user_id` as a text/varchar field requires more space, carefully defined constraints, etc.  It also leads to a massive update burden (thus threatening your db consistency) if you ever want to change a `user_id` value.  Better to have a user-friendly `user_id` field for *display-purposes only*, and use the `id` field for all your fk associations behind the scenes.

Comment: So, in my two AppModel.php files, how do I "make the association"?  How do I say User.id is tied to every Unit.id that has a user_id of "someuser"?

Comment: @HeatherWalters same way you did with your text field.  Just change the field name to the `id` field instead of `user_id`.  And instead of using user's text representations, use their unique `id`.  Cake will actually do this automagically for you if you use this naming convention.  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together#belongsTo-1042

Comment: Woo hoo, it worked!!!!!!  You rock, thank you!  I actually took out the "foreignKey=>'id' in my User.php file, and removed the containable feature in my controller and BLAMMO.  Thanks again.

Comment: I spoke too soon.  It only returned the user data for the very first unit.  The second item in the array returns empty values for the user keys.

Comment: @HeatherWalters it sounds like your foreign keys have invalid values then.  Inspect your units table and make sure that each unit has a fk value that corresponds to a valid id in your users table.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now.  I should have a field in my units table that IS the primary key "id" of the user, is this correct?

Comment: Ok, THAT did the trick.  Boy, model associations are HARD!!  Thank you!

Comment: @HeatherWalters Glad you got it figured out.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Unit->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'type' => 'condo',
            'active' => 1,
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'User',
        ),
    ));
```

Use containable to get related data.  You can use conditions within that contain as well to restrict what information you want.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable

Comment: Hmm, it still doesn't pull any 'User' data.  Seems like I am missing something still.

Comment: I altered my controller code.  public function condos() {

 $this->User->Behaviors->load('Containable');
 $u=$this->User->contain('Unit');
 $u=$this->User->find('all');
 $this->set('allcondos', $u);
 
 }
   It isn't associating the models together apparently because now I get all my data for User but not for Unit.